# Click on a javascript link with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, iframe

I generated a report through a website and I am trying to click on a link which exports the data into a csv file.

The element is:

```
    <span class="x21">
    <a style="color:#0000FF" href="javascript:JCRTYP('https://www.merchantconnect.com/CWRWeb/download.do?','CRCRDTYP','1','9507508464','01-FEB-2015','28-FEB-2015','14','2350','67156','WINN DIXIE 0283    S91','ALL','COMT');">
Comma Separated Value (CSV) </a>
        </span>
```

What I have now is to switch to the iframe and click it by the xpath. However, it throws a error "Unable to locate element". I even tried without switching to the iframe.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/span[4]/a").click()
```

The iframe source is:

```
<div class="iframes">
                <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 500px" name="FRAME1" src="/CWRWeb/nova/jsp/reports/running.jsp" align="middle" frameborder="no" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
                </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to the `iframe` by name:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("FRAME1")
```

And locate the link by link text:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Comma Separated Value (CSV)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I was in the wrong frame!